# Agrupar fechas en base a diferencia de más de 30 días entre dos consecutivas PySpark en Python 3.x

Tags: python, pyspark

Tenemos un sistema el cual trabaja mejor con la librería **pySpark** que Pandas, en relación a trabajar con grandes volúmenes de información.

Quiero realizar una consulta y quiero tener una agrupación la cual entre fechas para cada `'pfr_Fault_Code'` no existan más de 30 días desde la fecha más actual hacía atrás.

**Ejemplo:**

Para un `'pfr_Fault_Code'=XXXXXX` tengo las siguientes `'fault_date'=[2017/12/01],[2017/11/29],[2017/11/10],[2017/09/30],[2017/09/15]`

Desde la fecha más actual hacía atrás veo si existe un corte entre fechas superior a 30 días, el cual se genera entre `'[2017/11/10]` y `[2017/09/30]` por lo tanto me sirve `'fault_date'=[2017/12/01],[2017/11/29],[2017/11/10]`.

Si ejecutan el siguiente código, verán el resultado utilizando Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'pfr_Fault_Code': ["111111", "111111", "111111", "111111", "111111", 
                           "222222", "222222", "222222", "222222", "222222",
                           "333333", "333333", "333333", "333333"], 
            'fault_date': ["2017/12/01", "2017/11/29","2017/11/10", "2017/09/30", "2017/09/15", 
                           "2017/10/01", "2017/05/29","2017/05/10", "2017/03/30", "2017/03/30", 
                           "2017/05/01", "2017/04/29","2017/04/10", "2017/01/30"]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['fault_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fault_date'])

# Ordenamos de forma descendente las fechas, esto es un paso imprescindible
df.sort_values(by='fault_date', ascending = False, inplace = True)


df['groups'] = df.groupby('pfr_Fault_Code')['fault_date'].diff() < pd.Timedelta(days=-30)
df['groups'] = df.groupby('pfr_Fault_Code')["groups"].cumsum()
```

Con esto obtenemos el siguiente DataFrame:

```
   fault_date pfr_Fault_Code  groups
0  2017-12-01         111111     0.0
1  2017-11-29         111111     0.0
2  2017-11-10         111111     0.0
5  2017-10-01         222222     0.0
3  2017-09-30         111111     1.0
4  2017-09-15         111111     1.0
6  2017-05-29         222222     1.0
7  2017-05-10         222222     1.0
10 2017-05-01         333333     0.0
11 2017-04-29         333333     0.0
12 2017-04-10         333333     0.0
8  2017-03-30         222222     2.0
9  2017-03-30         222222     2.0
13 2017-01-30         333333     1.0
```

Ahora es muy simple obtener por cada valor de `pfr_Fault_Code` las filas hasta que una de las fechas de `fault_date` tiene una diferencia mayor de 30 días con respecto a la que le precede:

```
>>> df[df["groups"] == 0]

   fault_date pfr_Fault_Code  groups
0  2017-12-01         111111     0.0
1  2017-11-29         111111     0.0
2  2017-11-10         111111     0.0
5  2017-10-01         222222     0.0
10 2017-05-01         333333     0.0
11 2017-04-29         333333     0.0
12 2017-04-10         333333     0.0
```

El desafio es replicar esto mismo pero utilizando librería **PySpark** de la cual he realizado lo siguiente:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("example-spark")\
    .config("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled","true")\
    .getOrCreate()
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


df = spark.read.csv('FDE_before_delay_aviso_previo.csv', sep=',',header=True,dateFormat=['fault_date'],inferSchema = True)

#df.show()
df=df.sort('fault_date')
```

---

El archivo CSV para poder ejecutar el código es el siguiente:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f8IFNvMA0Zbm_t0whweZjt4QSHR-ahVy/view?usp=sharing